# Enumerate list of network computers and shared folders in a tree view?

Tags: delphi, treeview, delphi-xe2, file-sharing

I know there's plenty ways of enumerating computers and devices on a network, but how do I show just computers available for Windows file sharing? I need to provide a tree view of network computers and their shared folders. I know I could use existing shell controls for this, but I would rather keep it in my own tree view. It will only list those computers on the network which have shared folders. Past the computers and their shared folders, I can do the individual directory listing part myself. I just need to know how to get the computer list and their shared folder lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WNetOpenEnum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385478%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will give you all the computers on the network

> The WNetOpenEnum function starts an enumeration of network resources
>   or existing connections. You can continue the enumeration by calling
>   the [WNetEnumResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385449%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

[NetShareEnum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb525387%28VS.85%29.aspx) will you all shares on a machine.

> Retrieves information about each shared resource on a server.

You can use the combination of both to filter out what you don't want

Comment: Additional excerpt from Msdn **NetSharesEnum** entry: `You can also use the WNetEnumResource function to retrieve resource information. However, WNetEnumResource does not enumerate hidden shares or users connected to a share`: if enumerating hidden resources are part of the OP requirements **NetShareEnum** is not an option, is it?

Answer (score 3):

Please consider the following resources if you are interested in sample Delphi code using WNetOpenEnum/WNetOpenEnum Windows API:

- [Networked Drives](http://www.angusj.com/delphitips/netdrives.php) by Angus John:
- [Use the Windows API to generate a list of available Network Resources](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/26876) published in the EDN by Justin Swett
- [Get a list of computers in a network](http://www.delphitricks.com/source-code/internet/get_a_list_of_computers_in_a_network.html) from Delphitricks.com.

Having a good command of [NETRESOURCE structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385353%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) is also must.

I personnaly recommend the following listings from http://www.developpez.net's Forum:

Listing #1:

---

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, Unit2;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure EnumNetworkProc(const aNetResource :TNetResource; const aLevel :word; var aContinue :boolean);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.EnumNetworkProc(const aNetResource :TNetResource; const aLevel :word; var aContinue :boolean);
begin
  if aNetResource.dwDisplayType in [RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_DOMAIN, RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_SERVER] then
    ListBox1.Items.Add(StringOfChar(' ', aLevel*4) +aNetResource.lpRemoteName);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  EnumNetwork(EnumNetworkProc, RESOURCE_GLOBALNET, RESOURCETYPE_DISK);
end;

end.
```

---

Listing #2:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses Windows;

type
  TEnumNetworkProc = procedure(const aNetResource :TNetResource; const aLevel :word; var aContinue :boolean) of object;

procedure EnumNetwork(const aEnumNetworkProc :TEnumNetworkProc; const aScope :dword = RESOURCE_GLOBALNET; const aType :dword = RESOURCETYPE_ANY);

implementation

//Procédure récursive
procedure DoEnumNetwork(const aContainer :Pointer;
                        const aEnumNetworkProc :TEnumNetworkProc;
                        const aScope :dword;
                        const aType  :dword;
                        const aLevel :byte);
type
  PNetResourceArray = ^TNetResourceArray;
  TNetResourceArray = array [0..0] of TNetResource;
var
  NetHandle    :THandle;
  NetResources :PNetResourceArray;
  NetResult    :dword;
  Size, Count, i :Cardinal;
  Continue     :boolean;
begin
  Continue := TRUE;

  NetResult := WNetOpenEnum(aScope, aType, 0, aContainer, NetHandle);

  if NetResult = NO_ERROR then
  try
    //Taille de base
    Size := 50 *SizeOf(TNetResource);
    GetMem(NetResources, Size);

    try
      while Continue do
      begin
        Count := $FFFFFFFF;
        NetResult := WNetEnumResource(NetHandle, Count, NetResources, Size);

        //Taille insuffisante ?
        if NetResult = ERROR_MORE_DATA
        then ReallocMem(NetResources, Size)
        else Break;
      end;

      //Enumère
      if NetResult = NO_ERROR then
        for i := 0 to Count - 1 do
        begin
          //Callback
          if Assigned(aEnumNetworkProc) then
          begin
            aEnumNetworkProc(NetResources^[i], aLevel, Continue);
            if not Continue then Break;
          end;

          //Appel récursif
          if (NetResources^[i].dwUsage and RESOURCEUSAGE_CONTAINER) > 0 then 
            DoEnumNetwork(@NetResources^[i], aEnumNetworkProc, aScope, aType, aLevel +1);
        end;
    finally
      FreeMem(NetResources, Size);
    end;
  finally
    WNetCloseEnum(NetHandle);
  end;
end;

procedure EnumNetwork(const aEnumNetworkProc: TEnumNetworkProc; const aScope, aType: dword);
begin
  DoEnumNetwork(nil, aEnumNetworkProc, aScope, aType, 0);
end;

end.
```

---

Source: [Liste des machines sur un réseau local (tout le réseau de Win)](http://www.developpez.net/forums/d680475/environnements-developpement/delphi/web-reseau/liste-machines-reseau-local-reseau-win/#post3984824) - Original post (in French) by Lucas Panny.